# Windows 8 Jump List (Quick Launch, Task Bar) menu items background is too dark and icons misaligned

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, quicklaunch

On my new laptop with Windows 8 on initialization setup I probably chose a wrong background, which applied only to Quick Launch items context menu: now I can't see labels when i open any icon menu, see image below [image: Screenshot]

I tried to find this color setting in *Personalization*, *Task bar*, *Control Panel* and so on - no result.

So, the question is quite easy: **how do I restore default background color, or to set the labels color to light?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall the Update KB3072318. This is the update that shows the message to upgrade to Windows 10 during the OOBE. This update has a known bug which causes that problem. To remove the update, go to Control Panel -> Programs -> Installed Updates

Comment: Also, some explanation of how to do this would be useful.